# Generating a vector basis

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra, vector

I have several lists parameterizing a vector space, for instance

```
{a[1],a[2],a[1]+2 a[2]-a[3]}
```

For each list I want to generate a basis such as `{{1,0,1},{0,1,2},{0,0,-1}}` so that

```
{a[1],a[2],a[1]+2 a[2]-a[3]} == a[1] {1,0,1} + a[2] {0,1,2 } + a[3] {0,0,-1 }
```

The function `Position[]` does not look helpful for this.

Comment: What are the `a`'s supposed to be, basis vectors?

Comment: No, the a's are coefficients.

Comment: I think you jumped quite a bit; I'm not seeing how your coefficients map to basis vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Map[Coefficient[{a[1], a[2], a[1] + 2 a[2] - a[3]}, #] &, Table[a[i], {i, 3}]]
(*{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, -1}}*)
```

Answer (score 6):

`CoefficientArrays[]` does nicely for this:

```
CoefficientArrays[{a[1], a[2], a[1] + 2 a[2] - a[3]}, Array[a, 3]] // 
   Normal // Last // Transpose
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, -1}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

This is very short:

```
vec = {a[1], a[2], a[1] + 2 a[2] - a[3]};

Transpose[D[vec, {Array[a, 3]}]]

(* ==> {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, -1}} *)
```

It gets the basis from the columns of the Jacobian for the linear relation in `vec`.